# How should I create an iterator that also supports a tell() method?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I need to create a class that returns one character at a time from a stream of data using the iterator protocol, but that also has a method analogous to a file object's `tell()`, returning what position it is currently at in the stream.

Basically, this is what I need:

```
>>> x = MyIterator('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
>>> x.tell()
0
>>> next(x)
'a'
>>> next(x)
'b'
>>> next(x)
'c'
>>> x.tell()
3
>>> next(x)
'd'
>>> x.tell()
4
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this? Can I do it using a generator somehow, or do I have to create a class that implements the iterator protocol "by hand"? (i.e. a class with a `__next__()` method that manually raises `StopIteration` when it runs out of data)

Please note, this question is a bit of a simplification of what my actual needs are. I actually need the `tell()`-analogue to return a function of the stream position and not simply the position, so please don't tell me "just make the caller of my iterator use `enumerate()`" or something like that.

Comment: You should tell us your actual requirement as well, without the actual requirement, we would only be able to provide solution for the simplified version. Is the actual requirement still just a string , like given in your simplified version?

Comment: I'm writing a disassembler. The architecture I'm disassembling has instruction-pointer-relative addresses; to disassemble these correctly it is necessary to know the current IP (which is a mathematical function of the position in the stream, but one that varies depending on the image being disassembled, so I can't just bake it into the disassembler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I do it using a generator somehow

Not really.  (You could theoretically do it by storing the counter as a function attribute on the generator function, but trying to make a function refer to itself is a risky proposition.)

> or do I have to create a class that implements the iterator protocol "by hand"? (i.e. a class with a `__next__()` method that manually raises StopIteration when it runs out of data)

Yes and no.  Yes, you have to create an iterator class, but that doesn't mean you have to manually raise StopIteration.  Assuming you want your iterator to wrap some source iterable, then you can just rely on that source to raise StopIteration.  Here's a simple example:

```
class MyIter(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = iter(source)
        self.counter = 0

    def next(self):
        self.counter += 1
        return next(self.source)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def tell(self):
        return self.counter
```

(This uses `next` a la Python 2; for Python 3 you'd have to change `def next` to `def __next__`.)

Then:

```
>>> x = MyIter('abc')
>>> for item in x:
...     print(item, x.tell())
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Comment: @AlexJackson: What do you mean "is a `__iter__`"?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted an incomplete comment and then ran out of time to edit it. For my purposes, `tell()` doesn't absolutely have to be a method of the iterator itself, it just needs access to the state of the iterator. What if instead of implementing `next(self)`, the `MyIter` class `__iter__(self)` method is a generator that increments `self.counter` and yields from `self.source`? (I believe this would make MyIter an "iterable" rather than an "iterator"... I'm just starting to grasp the distinction between them) Would that also automatically handle exhaustion of the source?

Comment: @AlexJackson: Yes, that would work too, although it doesn't save you much over the above version.  It basically just means you put the contents of `next()` into `__iter__()`.  And yes, it would `MyIter` an iterable but not an iterator.  (In the above version it is both.)

Comment: Well, I wanted to avoid having different syntax for python 2 and python 3, but I just realized that I'm going to have to anyway because of the `str` vs `bytes` thing. If I make `next(self)` return `ord(next(self.source))` and `__next__(self)` return `next(self.source)` it kills two birds with one stone. The iterable version also has the disadvantage, which I also just realized, that calling `iter()` twice on the same `MyIter` object would create two iterators that share the same state rather than two independent iterators over the same data, which is... not intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too expensive to calculate it, have the iterator yield both the value and the position. Alternatively, provide two iteration methods, one that yields just the values and one that yields the values and the positions.